# Mobile version of the website moves to the sides

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I noticed a problem on my website. In the mobile version I can move to the sides. The page is not static. Totally I don't know where to look for the cause.

Totally I don't know where to look for the cause. I tried to add

```
body, html {
overflow-x: hidden!important;
width: auto!important;
}
```

Image:

[image]

[Website](http://dejda.e-kei.pl/test/nuar/)

I count on your help. Thank you!

Comment: To be clear, you're saying there is some horizontal scrolling happening on mobile? If so, I am not noticing this in Chrome. Could you please tell us what you're testing with and how?

Comment: I use iphone 8 and iphone 7. I tried Safari or Chrome on my mobile browser. The same problem on each of them. I added a preview photo.

Comment: Works fine in my browser too (chrome and firefox)

Comment: The issue seems to be only with iPhone browser. Works fine on others.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error and i could resolve apply this style in my main html
try with this and resolve the differents in your css that you get

```
<html lang="en"  style="padding: 0px;height:100%;width: 100%;" >
```